# Is there a way to use a string to get the adress values of registers defined in a include file?

Tags: string, system-verilog

Is there a way to use a string to get the adress values of registers defined in a include file?

In my testcase I include a file where register names are defined, for example like this:

```
`define SPECIFIC_REGISTER  24'h001234.
```

During my testtask I get the names of the registers I have to set out of a testfile, so that at some point I have a string with the value
            register="SPECIFIC_REGISTER"

Now I have to reach the corresponding adress of SPECIFIC_REGISTER ...

what i wanted to do is something like this:

```
        int adress = `register;
```

where register has the name SPECIFIC_REGISTER or SPECIFIC_REGISTER2 and so on.

But when i try it like this he always errors: undeclared identifier, because when I include the register definitions the string register is empty ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a string to access an variable name. What you can do is define an associative array whose elements are keyed with a string

```
bit [23:0] registers[string];

registers["SPECIFIC_REGISTER"] = 24'h0001234;
registers["SPECIFIC_REGISTER2"] = 24'h0005678;

registers[regname] = addrval;
```

where `regname` and `addrval` have been set to a string and value you read from a file.

```
address = registers["SPECIFIC_REGISTER"];
```

Comment: First of all, thanks Dave.
And is there a way to put all `defines of the include file in the Array or do i have to add them manually?

Comment: You could write a script to convert the defines into the array assignments. Actually, what most people do is create a spreadsheet with the register definitions, and then use a script to generate both the defines and the array